# How to display Inno Setup license page before custom page shows from procedure InitializeWizard()

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using `LicenseFile=D:\authorized\Builds\Integration\License.rtf` to display license page and procedure `InitializeWizard()`.

The **Problem** is that the license page is displayed **after** the procedure `InitializeWizard()`. Is there any way we can display it **before**?

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // Create the pages
  UsagePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,
    'App setup information', 'How would you like to install App?',
    'Would you like to install App as a service?.',
    True, False);
  UsagePage.Add('Yes');
  UsagePage.Add('No');
  UsagePage.Values[0] := true;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a misunderstanding. The `InitializeWizard` function does not display anything. It just creates the custom page(s), it does not display them.

*Try adding a `MsgBox` call at the end of the function. You will see that the message displays before the wizard form even pops up.*

---

The order of the custom pages is determined by the `AfterID` parameter (the first one) of the `Create*Page` functions.

If you want the custom page to show after the license page, use `wpLicense`, instead of `wpWelcome`.

```pascal
UsagePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpLicense, ...);
```